# autotools: don't include library when doing “make check”

Tags: c, testing, autotools, stubs

So I'm writing tests for my code, and I want to stub out the calls to library functions (make sure that it's calling the right library calls at the right time, and that it handles errors appropriately).

I think I'm SOL with the C standard library functions, but those aren't the only libraries I'm using.

When building my final executable (not my test executable), I want to use `-lfuse`, so I included this line in my `configure.ac`

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([fuse], [fuse_main])
```

However, this also tosses in `-lfuse` when it tries to build my `check_PROGRAMS`.

Is there some way I can tell autotools that I don't want the `-lfuse` library when building my test executable (`make check`)?  Then I should be able to stub out the library calls as I wish, since there won't be anything else linked with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that libfuse supplies a `fuse.pc` file in its source distribution, so the proper way to check for it is to use `pkg-config`. You can do

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([APPNAME], [fuse ...and any other libraries to check for...])
```

in your `configure.ac`, and then

```
appname_CFLAGS += @APPNAME_CFLAGS@
appname_LIBS += @APPNAME_LIBS@
```

in `src/Makefile.am`. Then just don't add those variables to your test programs.

Comment: Thanks.  So I can choose the first argument to PKG_CHECK_MODULES to be some arbitrary string, and it defines `<ARBITRARYSTRING>_CFLAGS` etc?  That's handy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured out *a* solution.  I'm not convinced it's the *right* solution, so I'll be checking back here to see if anyone can come up with anything better.

If I change the default success/failure actions in my `configure.ac` to

```
 AC_SUBST([HAVE_LIBFUSE])
 AC_CHECK_LIB([fuse], [fuse_main], [HAVE_LIBFUSE=1])
```

And then manually add `-lfuse` to my `<appname>_LDADD` flags in `src/Makefile.am`, then it's included just when I make the main executable, and I'm free to stub out the functions in my tests.

At least I think I am, and this is enough for me to move forward for now.